I'm having a problem with Wall Jumping Mechanic in 2D Platformer Java Game
So, i'm coding a 2D platformer in Java, i already made a wallslide mechanic, and the walljump works too, but i'm struggling with a detail in the walljump:
Suppose you're going right, when you jump to a wall, and get stuck to it, when you jump AGAIN, you go left (as you're supposed to), but if you keep holding right, instead of going right, you keep going left forever until you let go.
What i want is to have a mechanic like "Super Meat Boy", where, after a jump, there is a small delay to switch keys, but if you keep holding right, you go right.
this is my Player.Java's tick method (excuse the bad coding, it's all over the place lol)
public void tick() {

    
    //System.out.println("DashCooldown: " + dashCooldown + " TimeDashing: " + timeDashing);
    //dashing logic
    if (timeDashing > 0) {
        float dashDistance;

        // First half of the dash: high speed
        if (timeDashing < 10) {
            dashDistance = 30; // Maximum speed
        }
        // Second half of the dash: gradually slow down
        else {
            dashDistance = 3 * (timeDashing / 7.0f); // Ease-out effect
        }

        // Apply the dash distance
        if (forward) {
            setX(getX() + dashDistance);
        } else {
            setX(getX() - dashDistance);
        }
        

    }

    
    //sliding logic
    if(crouched && jumped== 0 && touchingWallSide == "none" && steppingOnSlideableBlock) {
        sliding = true;
    } else {
        sliding = false;

    }
    if(jumped ==0) {
        bufferedJumpCollision = false;
    }
    
    if(jumped >0 || getVelY() > 1.5 || getVelY() < -1.5) {
        steppingOnSlideableBlock = false;

        steppingOnBlock = false;
        slidingUnderBlock = false;

    }

    if (bufferedJumpIncoming && jumped == 0) {
        setVelY(-13);
        jumped+=1;

        bufferedJumpIncoming = false;

    }
    if(isWallSliding || wallJumpCooldown <= 0) {
        wallJumpCooldown = 50;
        wallJumpInputDelay = 10; 

    } 
    
    if (wallJumpCooldown < 50 && wallJumpCooldown > 0) {
        wallJumpCooldown --;

        //input delay
        
        if (wallJumpInputDelay > 0) {
            wallJumpInputDelay--;
        }

    }
    
    if(slidingCooldown <= 0) {
        slidingCooldown = 25;
    } 
    
    if (slidingCooldown < 25 ) {
        slidingCooldown --;
    }
    
    
    


    if (XMovementStopped) {
        // apply friction

        float velX = handler.getPlayer().getVelX();

        
        //if on the ground
        if(jumped == 0) {
            
            // reduce velocity gradually until it reaches 0
            if (velX > 0) {
                handler.getPlayer().setVelX(Math.max(velX - 0.8f, 0));
            } else if (velX < 0) {
                handler.getPlayer().setVelX(Math.min(velX + 0.8f, 0));
            }
            //if on the air after a wall jump
        } else if(jumped > 0) {
            if(wallJumpCooldown < 50) {
                
                    // reduce velocity gradually until it reaches 0
                    if (velX > 0) {
                        handler.getPlayer().setVelX(Math.max(velX - 0.2f, 0));
                    } else if (velX < 0) {
                        handler.getPlayer().setVelX(Math.min(velX + 0.2f, 0));
                    }
            } else {
                if (velX > 0) {
                    handler.getPlayer().setVelX(Math.max(velX - 0.8f, 0));
                } else if (velX < 0) {
                    handler.getPlayer().setVelX(Math.min(velX + 0.8f, 0));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    //set dashCooldown 
    if (dashCooldown < 15 && dashCooldown > 0) {
        dashCooldown--;
    } else if (dashCooldown <= 0) {
        dashCooldown = 15;
    }
    
    //set timeDashing 
    if (timeDashing > 0 && timeDashing < 15) {
        timeDashing += 2;
    } else if (timeDashing >= 15) {
        timeDashing = 0;
    }

    if (bulletCadence > 0 ) {
        shooting = true;
        
    } else if (bulletCadence == 0 ) {
        shooting = false;

    }
    if (bulletCadence < 10 && bulletCadence > 0) {
        bulletCadence++;
        
    } else {
        bulletCadence = 0;
    }

    // if the player is dead
    if (!alive) {

        // slowly decrease VelX
        if (getVelX() > 0) {

            setVelX(getVelX() - 0.1f);
        }
        if (getVelX() < 0) {
            setVelX(getVelX() + 0.1f);

        }

        setX((getVelX()) + getX());
        setY((getVelY()) + getY());

        applyGravity();

        return;
    }
    if (size == PlayerSize.Large) {

        if (tex.getCharacter() == "mario") {
            currSprite = spriteMarioL;
            currAnimation = marioWalkL;

        } else if (tex.getCharacter() == "bill") {
            currSprite = spriteBillL;
            currAnimation = billWalkL;

        }
    } else if (size == PlayerSize.Small) {

        if (tex.getCharacter() == "mario") {
            currSprite = spriteMarioS;
            currAnimation = marioWalkS;

        } else if (tex.getCharacter() == "bill") {
            currSprite = spriteBillS;
            currAnimation = billWalkS;

        }
    }

    //update X
    if(timeDashing > 0) {
        //if dashing, ignore velocity
        setX(getX());
    }else {
        //normal behaviour
        setX(getVelX() + getX());
    
    }
    
    //update Y
    if(timeDashing == 0) {
        //if not dashing
        setY(getVelY() + getY());
    }
    //limit x left side
    if (getX() < 0) {
        setX(0);    

    } 
    //limit x right side

    if (getX() > game.getLevelWidth() -48) {
        setX(game.getLevelWidth()-48);

    }
    


    if (isWallSliding) {
        
        if(!crouched) {
            if(wallJumpCooldown == 50) {
                
            setVelY(1f);
            }
            
        } else {
            setVelY(7f);

        }

    } else {
        applyGravity();
    }
    
    if(sliding) {
        if(forward) {
            setVelX(12f);               
        } else {
            setVelX(-12f);              

        }
    }

    collision();
    currAnimation.runAnimation("endless");
    if (getY() > 842) {
        killPlayer();
    }
    //System.out.println(getX());
    if(getVelX() >0) {
        forward = true;
    }
    if(getVelX() <0) {
        forward = false;
    }
}

The "magic" happens in KeyInput.Java, that's where the logic for wall jumping is:
package com.game.object.util;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


import com.game.gfx.Texture;
import com.game.main.Game;
import com.game.main.util.LevelHandler;
import com.game.object.Player;
import com.game.object.PlayerSize;


public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter{
    private boolean[] keyDown = new boolean[7];
    private Handler handler;
    private Game game;
    private LevelHandler levelHandler;
    

private Texture tex = Game.getTexture();

public KeyInput(Handler handler, Game game, LevelHandler levelHandler) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.game = game;
    this.levelHandler = levelHandler;
}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(game.getLoadingLevel()) {
        return;
    }
    
    Player player = handler.getPlayer();
    // Prevent inputs if the player is dead or if he entered a portal
    if (!player.getAlive() || player.getEnteredPortal() ) {
        return;
    }   
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    //reset 
    
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_R) {
        if(game.getLoadingLevel() == false) {               
            levelHandler.resetLevel();
        }
    }
    // jump
    if(  key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE ) {

            
        if(!keyDown[0]) {
            
        //if wall sliding
        if(player.isWallSliding() || player.getTouchingWallSide() != "none" ) {
            player.activateWallJumpCooldown();

            if(player.getTouchingWallSide() == "right") {
                keyDown[0] = true;

                player.setForward(false);
                
                player.setX(player.getX() - 16);
                player.setVelX(0);

                player.setVelY(-11);
                player.setVelX(-7);
                player.setIsWallSliding(false) ;
                player.setTouchingWallSide("none") ;

                


            } else if (player.getTouchingWallSide() == "left"){
                keyDown[0] = true;

                player.setForward(false);
                
                player.setX(player.getX() + 16);
                player.setVelX(0);

                player.setVelY(-11);
                player.setVelX(+7);
                player.setIsWallSliding(false) ;
                player.setTouchingWallSide("none") ;


            }
            player.setJumped(1);
            //if its a normal jump
        } else {
            if(player.hasJumped() == 0 ) {
                player.setJumped(player.hasJumped() + 1);
                player.setY(player.getY() -10);

                player.setVelY(-13);
                //System.out.println("normal jump");

                keyDown[0] = true;
            }
            if(player.hasJumped() == 1 && !keyDown[0]) {
                
                //with bufferedJump collision active
                if(player.getBufferedJumpCollision()) {
                    player.setBufferedJumpIncoming(true);
                } else {
                    
                //in the air
                player.setVelY(-11);
                keyDown[0] = true;
                player.setJumped(player.hasJumped() + 1);
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        }
        
    }
    
    //move left
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

        if(!keyDown[1]  ) { 
            if(!player.getSliding() ) {
                System.out.println("Sliding" + player.getSliding());
                System.out.println("SlidingCooldown:" + player.getSlidingCooldown());
            
                player.setForward(false);
                player.setVelX(-8);
            
                player.toggleXMovementStopped(false);
                player.setCrouched(false);

                keyDown[1] = true;
                keyDown[2] = false;
            }
            }
        

    }
    //move right
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

        if(!keyDown[2]) {
            if(!player.getSliding() ) { 
                player.setForward(true);
                player.setVelX(+8);
                player.toggleXMovementStopped(false);
                player.setCrouched(false);

                keyDown[2] = true;
                keyDown[1] = false;
            }
            }
        


    }
    
    //crouch 
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S || key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {

            
        if(player.getSteppingOnBlock()) {
            player.setCrouched(false);

        } else {
            
            player.setCrouched(true);
        }
        
        if(player.getSteppingOnSlideableBlock()) {              
            player.activateSlidingCooldown();
            player.setCrouched(true);

        
        }
        keyDown[3] = true;
        
    }
    
    
    // dash
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {

        if(!keyDown[4]) {
            
        player.dash();
        keyDown[4] = true;
        }
    }
    

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_Z) {
        if(!keyDown[5]) {
            player.parry();
            keyDown[5] = true;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // shoot bullet 
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_X) {

        if(!keyDown[6]) {
            
        player.shootBullet();
        keyDown[6] = true;
        }
    }
    
    //reset game 
    //if(key == KeyEvent.VK_R ) {
    //  
    //}

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(game.getLoadingLevel()) {
        return;
    }
    Player player = handler.getPlayer();

    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    
    // Prevent inputs if the player is dead or if he entered a portal
    if (!player.getAlive() || player.getEnteredPortal() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        keyDown[0] = false;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        if(!player.getSliding() ) {             
            keyDown[1] = false;
        }
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        if(!player.getSliding() ) {
            
        keyDown[2] = false;
        }
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S || key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        if(!player.getSlidingUnderBlock() && player.getSlidingCooldown() ==25) {
            
        player.setCrouched(false);
        keyDown[3] = false;
        }

    }
    
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
        
        
        keyDown[4] = false;
    }
    
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_X) {
        keyDown[6] = false;

    }
    //if(key == KeyEvent.VK_K) {
    //toggleCharacterSkin();

    //}
    //if(key == KeyEvent.VK_L) {
    //  player.togglePlayerSize();

    //}

    //if(key == KeyEvent.VK_R ) {
    //  Game game = new Game();
    //  game.outsideInitialize();
    //}
    
    if (!keyDown[1] && !keyDown[2]) {
        
        player.toggleXMovementStopped(true);
    }

}

public void toggleCharacterSkin() {
    System.out.println( tex.getCharacter());
    if( tex.getCharacter()== "mario") {
        tex.setCharacter("bill");
    } else if (tex.getCharacter() == "bill") {
        tex.setCharacter("mario");
    }
}





}

I've already tried adding a wallJumpInputDelay, and when it's equals to 0, you change direction to whatever key you are pressing, BUT it didn't work, because it seems like the movement is always the same until you let go of the key. (the idea is for it to change when you are holding down the key)
I hope that it's understandable, thanks so much for your attention.
